# What are the 'output_layer' Parameter Options for QGIS tool "saveselectedfeatures"?

Tags: pyqgis

After a few comments and my own consideration I've completely Edited the content (and title) of this post.

What are valid "output_layer" parameter options when scripting with the "saveselectedfeatures" tool?

I'm writing a script that uses the tool as follows:

```
processing.runandload('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', Input, 'Output.shp')
```

I also tried removing the shapefile extension and just putting 'Output' as the final parameter.  Still errors and no resulting output.

Don't worry about "Input", it's a perfectly valid layer with selected features.

PARTIAL SOLUTION

@Joseph provided the partial solution of replacing " 'Output.shp' " with " None " (no quotations).

```
processing.runandload('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', Input, None)
```

This results in successful execution with a temporary output layer called "Solution" popping up in the Layers Window.

BUT...

I call this a partial solution because I find it hard to believe that the designer(s) of this tool didn't also intend to give users the option to choose the name of their output file (as I originally tried to do) via the final parameter ('output_layer'), as described in the tool's Help Tab.

FINAL THOUGHTS

The tool's Help tab offers the following instruction:

[image]

[image]

But it seems this is not quite as "helpful" as it could be.  It seems like a few short and simple examples of acceptable values for the 2nd parameter would avoid any confusion.

Something like:

```
Output file options:  temporary layer, Shapefile, etc...

2nd Parameter ('output_layer') options:  
" 'User_chosen_name' " (or " 'User_chosen_name.shp' "), OR "None" (produces auto-named temporary layer).
```

I'm a relatively new user of QGIS.

Comment: As an FYI, you can replace `runalg` with `runandload` to load the output shapefile into QGIS.

Comment: @user3309182 - Most welcome buddy :)

Comment: Thanks @Joseph.  A great tip to know!  I'm using "runandload" now but nothing is loading.  Obviously something is still wrong with one of my two parameters.

Comment: @user3309182 - Could you [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/168405/edit) your question please to include your script so that potential answerers have a better chance of helping you? :)

Comment: @Joseph - Complete code now added but figured that would be distracting to the question since I'm quite confident it has no bearing on why "saveselectedfeatures" is failing.  Reasoning:  I know the first parameter is fine since "Input" is understood by another tool in my script.  That leaves just the 2nd parameter where I figure the problem must be.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @user3309182 - Yup, makes sense. What happens if you replace `'Output'` with `None` to create a temporary output?

Comment: @Joseph - Complete code now added.

Comment: @Joseph - When I put "None" (without quotes) it works!  The output appears on my project as "Selection".  I've also tried "Output.shp" but that doesn't work.  I have to step away for a few hours but if there's anything further you can suggest, many thanks!

Comment: @Joseph - I guess technically your suggestion to replace " 'Output' " with "None" is a solution.  But surely the designer(s) of the tool intended to allow users to put more than just "None" here?  Surely they intended users to be able to chose a name for their output file in that parameter location?

Comment: Oh most definitely they designed it so users can custom name their outputs. I'm not an expert in this field but what I normally do is when working with a single output file, I would simply define the path and name as the output (e.g. `C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Test//Shapefile_name.shp`). Or if I am working with multiple output files, I would use the `for` loop like `for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):`, then the output would be `"C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Test//" + fname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out (on a Mac at least) you have to put the full path plus the name for your file.  For example, the following code places the output shapefile "MyFile" on my desktop.

```
path = "/Users/User1/Desktop/"
processing.runandload('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', Input, path+'MyFile.shp')
```

Seems obvious in hindsight but again better documentation in the Help tab would have been a simple way to avoid confusion.

Still need to figure out why the output gets loaded onto map project as "Selection" and not with the name I provided ("MyFile"), but I've already asked that question in another post ("How to write QGIS script to load Output file to Map Project with Desired Name?")