# Making Scripted Tools Load Output File Automatically into QGIS Project?

Tags: pyqgis

When writing your own scripts, and using some of the pre-fab tools how do you make the output load automatically into your QGIS project?

Example: In the Help Tab of the QGIS tool "saveselectedfeatures" it explains its "Console Usage" as follows:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', input_layer, output_layer)
```

But when you run it as its own tool from the Toolbox the GUI has you fill in the same two parameters, but also has a third: a checkbox for "Open output file after running algorithm".  I checked it and it showed up as promised on my map project.

But the Tool's own HELP tab says nothing about how to script this functionality.

So how do I make the output open in the project automatically?

Comment: As mentioned in a previous [comment](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168405/suspected-problems-with-parameters-of-qgis-tool-saveselectedfeatures-scriptin#comment250922_168405) to another question of yours, you can replace `runalg` with `runandload`. Or do you still have issues with this?

Comment: No issues remaining @Joseph,  but I was advised to separate this question into its own designated post to be in keeping with the recommended "one question per question".  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to replace 'runalg' with 'runandload' (as suggested by @Joseph).

Comment: Does this question require a longer answer or explanation?  I feel the context is fully given in the question wording, complete with relevant code.  The answer is quite simply to replace 'runalg' with 'runandload'.  I referenced the person who supplied the solution, "@Joseph", in my answer.  Otherwise I am genuinely confused about what you mean by citations.